# MySQL limit a query with beginning at end

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a MySQL Table which contains two columns and I perform (it could not be simpler) a query

```
select * from test order by prio asc, datum asc
```

which gives me as expected this result:

```
datum      | prio
2017-07-02 | 1 
2017-07-09 | 2
2017-06-11 | 3
2017-06-01 | 4
2017-06-18 | 5
2017-06-25 | 6
```

Now, I want to limit my result to have ONLY the last 3 rows, with avoid doing something with an offset, because then I have to count the rows, so I know that this works:

```
select * from test order by prio asc, datum asc limit 3,3
```

But is there a trick, that I can do something similar to:

```
select * from test order by prio asc, datum asc limit -3
```

I know this fails.

Thank you

Comment: an idea is inverse order

Comment: change your sort order to display the desired rows first and take the first three

Comment: `order by prio desc` instead of `asc`, then just get the first 3 rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last N rows from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708992/mysql-limit-from-descending-order or etc. Do try to search!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below query.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY prio DESC LIMIT 0,3
) t ORDER BY prio ASC, datum asc;
```

Subquery will sort descending based on priority and return last 3 records. Outer query will again sort those priorities in ascending order and then sort on datum.

Hope this will help you.