# Where to put the DESC LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Where do i put the Desc limit, doesnt work to put it at the end :/

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN videos ON videos.catid=category.id WHERE videos.favorite = '1' DESC LIMIT 5";
```

I only get warning
: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: This might be helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708992/mysql-limit-from-descending-order

Comment: DESC and LIMIT are 2 different things. DESC should be after an ORDER BY.

Comment: SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN videos ON videos.catid=category.id WHERE videos.favorite = '1' ORDER BY category.id DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM category 
INNER JOIN videos ON videos.catid=category.id 
WHERE videos.favorite = '1' 
ORDER BY category.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

I have used `ORDER BY category.id`, but you may use your preferable field.